# Workflow, NativeActivity and Callback

Tags: c#, callback, workflow-foundation-4

I have workflow in C#. This workflow writes some text to the console and then is running Method with callback.. (another NativeActivity) Unfortunatelly, the callback is not fired.. Does somebody knows, how to run in NativeActivity or CodeActivity method with callback?

Petr

Comment: See if this codeproject helps : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was, that the workflow was ended before the callback came.. So I had to use: 

 ManualResetEvent